# A work flow planner that can possibly link mobile and desktop?

Tags: project-management

I'm looking for a something that I can use to plan tasks for my work days in advance that I can link with someone else so we can both add to it and if possible, to easily be accessed from mobile (Android).

I would like something that's simple and clear to use where I can add tasks to time slots in the day and easily keep track of and edit the tasks along with a colleague.

Answer (score 1):

[Wunderlist](http://www.wunderlist.com/) is the solution I use for managing lists and tasks and I'm very happy with it. To give you an idea of its pros and cons:

**Pros:**

- Can optionally specify deadline dates and add notes against each task.
- Tasks can be ordered and optionally marked with a star.
- Tasks can be viewed by list, by starred, by due today or due this week.
- Can be accessed and managed via website, desktop application or mobile app.

**Cons:**

- Lists can't have sub-lists.
- There are no workflows that would take an item from one status to a another.
- Tasks cannot be assigned a start time or expected duration, however you could type this into the task caption and manually order the tasks by start time.

I would definately recommend you try it even if it turns out this isn't the right solution for you.